# Using a macro for a small operation, is this good practice?

Tags: c, macros

I have a small piece of code that requires to read 4-bit values bitpacked in a 32-bit integer. Since I need to call this operation several times, even if it's simple, I require max speed on it.
I was pondering about macros and inline functions, thus I made this macro:

```
#define UI32TO4(x, p) (x >> ((p - 1) *4) & 15)
```

And I have an inline function that does the same thing.

```
static inline Uint8 foo_getval(Uint32 bits, int pos){
    return (bits >> ((pos-1)*4)) & 15;
}
```

Considering the simplicity of the operation, and that the values are already prepared for this call (so no possibility of calling on the wrong types, or pass values that are too big or that stuff), what would be the best one to use? Or, at least, the most comprehensible for someone else potentially reading/modifying the code later on?

EDIT! Forgot to mention, I am using C99.

Comment: I'm not sure about inline functions in C, but I think that the `inline` keyword is just a suggestion. Macros are always "inlined". On the other hand, using a function allows the compiler to do better typechecking.

Comment: You should (almost) always enclose macro parameters in parentheses in the replacement: `#define UI32TO4(x, p) ((x) >> (((p) - 1) * 4 & 15)`.  The exception is when the parameter is passed as an argument to a function (e.g. `#define FUNC(x, y) otherfunc(x, y)`); when it is part of an expression, enclose in parentheses.

Comment: **Trust your compiler: use the inline function.**

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I am going do that. What's the reasoning, though? I just ask out of curiosity. Anyway, it seems the inline function is the way to go. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Delirium_4: imagine a call like this: `SOME_MACRO(a+b,c)` - if you don't have parens around your macro parameters, the evaluation of the macro code might not do what you think it does.

Comment: Why didn't you name the macro arguments `bits` and `pos` like you did for the function? Macro arguments can be descriptive too :)

Comment: @pmg Actually I wrote the macro first, but then rewrote it as a function in the style of the others I use. You can say the macro was the prototype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function is safer. Your assumptions that the values are always "right" only holds while you're developing that code. You can't tell if someone down the line (or yourself when you're tired) won't pass unexpected values.

The compiler will do the inlining when it sees it as effective. Use type-safe functions whenever you can, use macros only when you have no other practical choice.

Comment: Ah, I am concerned about who might want to reuse the code after I am done. I understand then, I will go with the inline function.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the inline function because macros can cause unwanted side effects. Use macros only to save typing if necessary.

If a macro name is the same name as a function name in an other compilation unit you would get strange compilation errors. These problems can be hard to find, especially if the macro is expanded elsewhere and no error occurs.

Additionally a function warns you about parameter types and would not let you give a double for pos. The macro could allow this.

Answer (score 2):

It's late, and I'm grumpy (and I'll probably delete this post later) but I get tired of hearing the same arguments against macros parroted over and over again (a double redundacy):

- Joachim Pileborg (above) states "using a function allows the compiler to do better typechecking". This is *often stated*, but I don't believe it. With macros, the compiler already has *all* the available type information at its fingertips. Functions simply destroy this. (And possibly destroy optimization, by pushing registers out to the stack, but that's a side issue.)
- And frast (above) states "macros can cause unwanted side effects". True--but *so* can functions. I think the rule  is **to always use UPPER_CASE for macros** which ***don't*** have function semantics. This rule has often been broken. But it doesnt apply here: the OP has redundantly used *both* uppercase *and* function semantics.

But I would suggest a tiny improvement. The OP has quite correctly placed parentheses around the whole macro, but there should also be parentheses around each argument:

```
   #define UI32TO4(x, p) ((x) >> (((p) - 1) * 4) & 15)
```

*Always* enclose your macro args in parentheses, unless you are doing string or token concatenting, etc.

Macros are, of course, dangerous, but so are functions. (And the less said of `STL,` the better).

Comment: Oh, you might be late and grumpy, but it's a very interesting answer nevertheless. It's good to have arguments for both sides. I am only not too clear on what you mean with using upper case for macros that don't...that means I should do macro functions in lower case instead? (really sorry, not English native, I get lost with minor things at times...you might not even be meaning that)